# Firebase UI authentication "Identity Toolkit API" error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am going round in circles with Firebase UI for authentication.

I am using some code I have used previously, which worked OK, which is pretty much based on the samples.

My issue is when using either EmailBuilder orGoogle Builder, my attempts to authenticate from a hardware device give the error:

```
E/AuthUI: A sign-in error occurred.
com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Identity Toolkit API has not been used in project xxxxxx before or it is disabled...
```

I've verified the Firebase Sign-in methods and SHAs are set up correctly.

> Versions: 
>       com.google.gms:google-services: 4.1.0
>       com.android.support:appcompat-v7: 27.1.1
>       com.android.support:design: 27.1.1
>       com.android.support:customtabs: 27.1.1
>       com.android.support:cardview-v7: 27.1.1
>       com.google.firebase:firebase-core: 16.0.1
>       com.google.firebase:firebase-database: 16.0.1
>       com.google.firebase:firebase-auth: 16.0.3
>       com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth: 4.0.0
>       com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth: 15.0.1

I've lost a few hours on this already. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Google id\_token is not allowed to be used with this application. Firebase access fails after it was working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40450850/error-google-id-token-is-not-allowed-to-be-used-with-this-application-firebase)

Comment: found any solutions?

Comment: @FebinMathew - it was an optional part of a course assignment submission. In the end, due to time constraints, I had to abandon the use of EmailBuilder.